# get UITableViewCell from NSIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, nsindexpath

I am using multiple `UITableView` with custom cells in a single `viewController`. Custom cell have `textFields`, I am able to edit the textFields. Now I want to get the tableViewCell of exact `UITableView` in the `textField` delegate method when am editing the textField ?

Remember there are multiple tableViews I want to get the exact cell of exact table which am editing. Any Help?

Comment: I will suggest looping to upper views till you get an instance of uitableviewcell then check if it is kind of your custom class

Comment: I would recommend that the view controller only manages a single table view.

Comment: in your both tableview have textfield??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have **tag** to your both **tableview**

use below code in textfield delegate

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview.superview;
UITableView *curTableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [curTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. If Apple ever change the view hierarchy your app will not work (they have done this before).

Answer (score -1):

NEVER loop through superviews, the correct and most reliable way to do what you want is:

```
    CGPoint textViewPosition = [textView convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    CGRect senderFrame = CGRectMake(textViewPosition, textViewPosition, textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height);
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForRowsInRect:senderFrame];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[indexPaths firstObject];
```

This may get more complex as you have different table views in 1 view, I suggest rethinking why you have more than 1 table view and see if you can't do this in a more efficient way i.e. 1 table view with custom sections etc...

Comment: this scenario not possible in this code  
because in textfield method  we don't know about tableview for 
[textView convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

Comment: You need to restructure your code so that the delegate is in the correct place.